# Understanding the process of tweaking contrasts in linear model fitting to show all levels

Tags: regression, categorical-data, linear-model, categorical-encoding, contrasts

The accepted answer to this question on SO accomplishes exactly what I need: [Comparing all factor levels to the grand mean: can I tweak contrasts in linear model fitting to show all levels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72820236/comparing-all-factor-levels-to-the-grand-mean-can-i-tweak-contrasts-in-linear-m)

However, I don't understand exactly what the process is doing. Could you explain how sum-to-zero contrast coding is being used for this purpose?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to know a bit more precisely? For one, there are easier ways to calculate contrasts (in R). Do you want a short explanation of the SO code (in which case -- this question might be off-topic). Or do you want a short explanation of contrasts?

Comment: Does [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/168858/136579) or [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/591518/136579) answer help your understanding?

Comment: Take a look at the [contrast](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/contrast/index.html) package and its [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/contrast/vignettes/contrast.html) or the [emmeans](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html) package and its [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/comparisons.html) about contrasts. In most cases there is no need to calculate contrasts explicitly.

Comment: @dipetkov- I understand what contrasts are. I don't understand the process they used so that we can compare all levels to the grand mean, rather than leaving one level as the reference level.

Comment: So let's say on the balance you are interested in an explanation of the SO answer code.

Comment: Sounds about right. But also why they are doing what they’re doing.

Comment: I don't know why they suggest this solution. It's not the only solution. So I'll hint one last time that an alternative way to formulate this question is to abstract away from the details of someone else's code and describe the statistical question you are solving. There are lots of CV threads about contrasts; it might help do read some of them.

Comment: A related question is: [Two-way ANOVA with modified sum-to-zero constraint](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/301243/) Interestingly, I answered that post myself which I had completely forgotten about. It might be a better explanation of the relationship between contrasts and the 'sum-to-zero' than what I did here.

Answer (score 0):

Say that we have a vector $\begin{bmatrix} x_A & x_B & x_C \end{bmatrix}$ for the categories, where the $x_i$ can take values 0 or 1,

- then  the model without contrasts is:

  $$\hat{y}(x_A,x_B,x_C) = \mu + \beta_1 \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot  \begin{bmatrix} x_A\\ x_B \\ x_C \end{bmatrix} + \beta_2 \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot  \begin{bmatrix} x_A\\ x_B \\ x_C \end{bmatrix} = \mu + \beta_1 x_B + \beta_2 x_C$$

  or for the cases where exactly one of the values $x$ is equal to 1

  $$\hat{y}(x_A,x_B,x_C) = \begin{cases} 
  \mu & \quad \text{if $x_A= 1$, $x_B = 0$ and $x_C = 0$}\\
  \mu + \beta_1 & \quad \text{if $x_A= 0$, $x_B = 1$ and $x_C = 0$}\\
  \mu + \beta_2 & \quad \text{if $x_A= 0$, $x_B = 0$ and $x_C = 1$}\\
  \end{cases}$$
- then the model with contrasts is:

  $$\hat{y}(x_A,x_B,x_C) = \mu + \beta_1 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot  \begin{bmatrix} x_A\\ x_B \\ x_C \end{bmatrix} + \beta_2 \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot  \begin{bmatrix} x_A\\ x_B \\ x_C \end{bmatrix} = \mu + \beta_1 (x_A-x_C) + \beta_2 (x_B-x_C)$$

  or for the cases where exactly one of the values $x$ is equal to 1

  $$\hat{y}(x_A,x_B,x_C) = \begin{cases} 
  \mu + \beta_1 & \quad \text{if $x_A= 1$, $x_B = 0$ and $x_C = 0$}\\
  \mu + \beta_2 & \quad \text{if $x_A= 0$, $x_B = 1$ and $x_C = 0$}\\
  \mu - \beta_1 - \beta_2 & \quad \text{if $x_A= 0$, $x_B = 0$ and $x_C = 1$}\\
  \end{cases}$$

> However, I don't understand exactly what the process is doing. Could you explain how sum-to-zero contrast coding is being used for this purpose?

What this second model, with the contrasts, is doing is that you get that the intercept $\mu$ is equal to the sum of the estimate for the three groups $$\hat{y}(1,0,0) + \hat{y}(0,1,0) + \hat{y}(0,0,1) = \mu$$ So the intercept is now the mean of the groups (instead of the mean of the group A).

---

Inference.

In the output table of `lm` only $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are shown, and you also want to know whether $-\beta_1-\beta_2$ is significant. This is what you need the covariance matrix for (to compute the standard error of $-\beta_1-\beta_2$). It accounts for the fact that the distribution of the estimated $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are correlated. Say that an individual from group C in your sample has a larger value, then this has an effect on both $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$, the two estimates are not independent.